# Elasticsearch range query on date field always gives empty result

Tags: json, elasticsearch, range

Elasticsearch v6.8, I'm trying to make a basic query to retrieve documents with a date field in a specific range. But no matter which range I specify, I always get empty result.

This is an example of a document:

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 4,
    "successful" : 4,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 56657,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "myindex",
        "_type" : "mydoc",
        "_id" : "sRUe8mIB6XnnZk5zfobC",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "createdAt" : "2018-04-19T12:46:03Z",
          "id" : 10465929,          
          "type" : 2          
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've also tried a slightly modified query from the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/query-dsl-range-query.html) to get documents with a date before today...but same (empty) result:

```
GET /myindex/mydoc/_search
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "createdAt": {
                "lt" :  "now/d"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 4,
    "successful" : 4,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Tried also with `POST` instead of `GET`, same result. The field `createdAt` is definitely of type `date` in the index (e.g. format `2018-04-19T12:46:03Z`). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `"lt" :  "now"` (without `/d`). If the problem still persists, please share some sample docs.

Comment: @jzzfs Tried without `/d` but again empty result. I've added a document sample in the question

Answer (score 0):

It's not reproductible -- the following works perfectly fine:

```
DELETE myindex          // careful here

POST myindex/_doc
{
  "createdAt": "2018-04-19T12:46:03Z",
  "id": 10465929,
  "type": 2
}

GET myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "createdAt": {
        "lt": "now/d"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Does the following throw an exception?

```
GET myindex/_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "formatted_date": {
      "script": {
        "source": """
                  LocalDateTime.ofInstant(
                     Instant.ofEpochMilli(doc['createdAt'].value.millis),
                     ZoneId.of('Europe/Vienna')
                  ).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

What if you try adding a doc w/ a `random_id` that you'll later delete?

```
POST myindex/mydoc/random_id
{

  "createdAt": "2018-04-19T12:46:03Z",
  "id": "random_id",
  "type": 2
}
```

And run the search again.

Comment: No, it works fine returning `formatted_date` field in the new format